# MATLAB - Pole placement not resulting in correct eigenvalue matrix

Tags: matlab

I am trying to design a Luenberger observer such that with one sensor available I can estimate all the states.

My system is 4th order:

```
NUM4 = [-0.00198 2];
DEN4 = [1 0.1201 12.22 0.4201 2];
sys = tf(NUM4,DEN4);
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(NUM4,DEN4);
```

First I have a row vector of poles to get my desired response:

```
p1 = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120];
K = acker(A,B,p1)
p_1 = eig(A-B*K) %This should be the same as p1, but it is not
```

I then proceed to calculate the plant poles and thus the poles I want for my observer should be around 3x faster.

```
rank(ctrb(A,B)) % =4
rank(obsv(A,C)) % =4
planteig=eig(A);
fastpoles = 3*planteig;
```

I then proceed to use Ackermann's formula for pole placement using the new poles:

```
L=acker(A',C',p2)
L=L'
p_2 = eig(A-L*C) %This should be the same as p2
```

And finally plot:

```
mysys=ss(A-B*K,B,C,0);
step(74826*mysys)
```

---

Following this [document](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~khan/Courses/Spring2013/EE194/Lecs/Lec6and7.pdf) on how to build observers, there is written on page 6 that we can verify the pole placement by calculating `A-B*K` which should be the same as the poles placed inside Ackermann's formula:

[image]

This does not hold in my case, and thus I am suspecting that the resulting matrix values are incorrect.

The eigenvalues for `eig(A-B*K)` are:

```
ans =

   1.0e+02 *

  -1.2000 + 0.0000i
  -1.0000 + 0.0000i
  -0.0260 + 0.0239i
  -0.0260 - 0.0239i
```

which is not equal to `p1` = `p1 = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120];`

and `eig(A-L*C)` =

```
ans =

  -0.0505 + 1.2211i
  -0.0505 - 1.2211i
  -0.1296 +10.4136i
  -0.1296 -10.4136i
```

which is equal to `p2` but poles are not in correct order =

```
  -0.1296 +10.4136i
  -0.1296 -10.4136i
  -0.0505 + 1.2211i
  -0.0505 - 1.2211i
```

Why are the eigenvalues not matching the original poles in my case, as stated in the document? AM I coding up something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your problem with `p1`. You get eigen values in different order but it corresponds to `p1` up to a permutation.

All in all, I don't see any code mistake here; your problem is that `eig` *may* sort the eigen values (in decreasing magnitude), it is not always the case. If you need to ensure a specific ordering, you must do extra coding for that.